# One server has multiple IP address leases but just one adapter and no dhcp reservations?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, dhcp, ping, dhcp-server

One of our servers' has multiple (10) DHCP Addressleases and I don't know why. The server itself has only one adapter and even if I execute `ipconfig /all` I only see one IP address defined. Even in the adapter settings I'm not able to see the IPV 4 Protocol settings where I might could define multiple IP Addresses:

[image]

Furthermore on the DHCP server there are no reservations defined. The server gets addressleases from the defined addresspool. All these addresses are not pingable but they get renewed every 24 hours.

The server mentioned which receives multiple DHCP addresses is a Windows Server 2003 R2 Server. The DHCP Server is a Windows 2008 R2 server.

So what are these addresses for if I can't ping them? What Service is able to get DHCP addresses?

Thanks in advance for your help!

[image: DHCP IP Addresses with 24h address leases]

The RRAS Service is not active but not configured. In order to configure the RRAS Service I need to disable the Firewall/Shared Internet Connection service. 
[image: RRAS]

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the dhcp leases the server is getting from the dhcp server?

Comment: Any virtualization software running on the server?

Comment: If it really is getting actual dhcp leases and HOLDING them, then my bet is either virtualization like Thomas stated, or the server might have RRAS enabled and getting its WAN-miniport addresses via DHCP.

Comment: Sounds like RRAS to me too.

Comment: There is a client-server software running on the server but no virtualization. About RRAS I checked the Service and it says "started but not configured". Furthermore I added the DHCP Address Leases Print-Screen as well as a RRAS Print-Screen. If I want to configure it, it says that i need to disable the service "Firewall/Shared Internet Connection". What does this mean?